# Open a excel file and Add cell value

Tags: c#, excel, addition, xlsx

I use C# & Excel Intropt.dll for my project

I want Open my xlsx file and adding a value (For Example "1") to All Of my cells in Sheet1.

How can i achieve this?

Like this:

```
12   14    19    22

81   91    26    62
```

Result:

```
13   15    20    23

82   92    27    63
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snippet. Cells[1,1] is the first cell at the top left corner. This gets the first sheet, but you can also reference them by name.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//You can loop through all cells and use i and j to get the cells
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1].Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1].Value2) + 1;

xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: OK, Can I Use Macro command replace whith "value" ?

Do you now this command ? (I want add 1 to per cell value)

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Do you know what are the values you want to insert? "Value" is just a variable name, you can replace it by anything. You can create two loops to iterate all the cells you want and attribute values to each of them.

Comment: ex for my bad english :)

How I can get value of cell[1,1] ?

Comment: Value2 contains the cell's value. You can read or write in it.

Comment: I did that but mine didn't save the updated rows in the spreadsheet for some reason...