# Exporting Database Data to Excel With Default Rows via SSIS or VB Script Task

Tags: vb.net, excel, ssis

I really need help desperately,I have been goggling for hours but am unable to find a good sample for the following problem.

Currently I am able to export a Data table to excel via the format below

```
    Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4  
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u 
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u 
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u
```

But I require the Top 2 Row of the excel to be imprinted with a default set of data.

Example of what i need listed below

```
    Created by: xxxxx
    Date Created: xxxxxxxx
    Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4  
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u 
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u 
    Data-- x   Data-- y   Data-- z   Data-- u
```

Any workaround to add the default 2 row via SSIS /windows script/application that can be scheduled is greatly appreciated. Guide to any tutorial would also be good.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Let the SSIS export the data first, and manipulate the excel file at least. That means, after `Data Flow` task put a c# `Script Task` to open workbook, insert two lines and finally set the values of cells:

1. [Open workbook, insert line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304469/how-to-add-new-row-to-excel-file-in-c-sharp)
2. [Set value of cells [1,1], [2,1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141440/open-a-excel-file-and-add-cell-value)